# Knockout binding for gijgo treeview with checkbox

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, treeview

I like the gijgo treeview with checkbox as its clean and neat and it solves the purpose of showing the hierarchy information. Check below link for documentation.

https://gijgo.com/tree/demos/bootstrap-treeview-checkbox

Since knockout.js is preferred for the front end development hence its needed to develop a knockout binding for this particular requirement.

The idea is to populate the hierarchy data from the backend and bind it to the custom knockout binding.

The user selects/un-selects some checkboxes and then hits the save button. the selected/unselected data is again sent back to the server for the save.

The below code is the usage of the control in jquery.

The function `tree.getCheckedNodes()` returns the array of selected checkboxes.

How would one call the above function from an knockout binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tree = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

  },

  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor() || {};
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var tree = $(element).tree(value);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `init` method:

- Unwrap the widget's initial data passed by your viewmodel from the `valueAccessor`
- Convert the initial data to the format the tree widget understands
- Initialize the widget with the correct settings `$(element).tree({ /* ... */ })`
- Attach an event listener (`.on("change", function() { }`) to track user-input

  - In the event listener function, write back the data from the UI to the viewmodel (e.g. `valueAccessor() (tree.getCheckedNodes())`)
- Optional: add [custom disposal logic](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html) to clean up the widget if knockout removes it from the DOM

In the `update` method, which is called if your view model's value changes

- Implement the logic that updates the widget based on your new settings. Probably something like `tree.check(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()))`. Make sure the update is "silent", if it would trigger a `change` event, you'd end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The "checkBoxChange" is the event. How should i write the data back to the viewmodel . for e.g tree.getCheckedNodes() returns the array of all the selected nodes. Need to set these array to an observableArray.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Was able to get it.